# how surjection between two sets imply bijection?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose there exist a surjection from set A to set B and there also exist a surjection from set B to set A . Does that imply there should exist a bijection from set A to set B?

Comment: Yes, if you assume the axiom of choice. In the absence of choice there need not be one.

Comment: their inverses are injections and then you apply Cantor Schroeder

Comment: @CarryonSmiling: Without $\mathsf{AC}$ they may not have (right) inverses.

Comment: can you provide a proof for that ?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see, thanks. I was aware of that though.